# Mean and concentration of $|\langle a, u\rangle|$ with Rademacher random vector $u$

Tags: random-variables, absolute-value, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

Suppose $u\sim\text{Unif}\{\pm1\}^n$ is a Rademacher random vector with iid components. Moreover, $a\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a fixed arbitrary integer vector.  I know that we can easily analyze $\langle a, u\rangle^2$ But I would like to know the distribution of $|\langle a, u\rangle|$? Is the expectation a function of $\|a\|_1$?. What is the concentration around its mean?

Comment: The expectation is definitely not a function of $\|a\|_1$; just try $a=(2,0)$ and $a=(1,1)$. The first will have expectation $2$ while the second will have expectation $1$. Still, $\langle a,u\rangle$ is sub-Gaussian so the absolute value has nice tail bounds.

Comment: I forgot, one other thing: the Khintchine inequality yields $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|a\|_2\leq \mathbb{E}[\vert \langle a,u\rangle\vert]\leq \|a\|_2$ (the upper bound is also just Cauchy-Schwarz/Jensen's inequality). This is probably close to about as good as you can do in general.

Comment: I see! so both comments suggest that the quantity is far away from $\|a\|_1$ which is what I tried to reconstruct. Is there some random-projection equation along these lines on vector $a$ that in expectation leads to $\|a\|_1$?